# How can I implement Column Reordering using react-data-grid?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-data-grid

In my REACT app I'm using npm package [react-data-grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-grid). On their website they provide an example of Column Reordering. I want to do exactly the same in my code.

I checked their source code but what I don't understand is how can I import all of the components they are using for columns reordering. Do I need to reimplement in my code all of the components they are using? Isn't a way to simply import them in my react app?

For example, for columns reordering, they are using the DraggableHeaderRenderer component. Is there a way to import this in my app instead of having all of its source code reproduced in my app?

Answer (score 0):

to use `react-data-grid` in your app, you need to import `DraggableHeaderRenderer`. I'll provide you a step-by-step.

1. Install the react-data-grid package: `npm install react-data-grid`
2. Import everything you need:

   import React from 'react';
   import ReactDataGrid from 'react-data-grid';
   import { DraggableHeader } from 'react-data-grid-addons';
3. Define the data and columns for the grid.
4. Create the main component that renders the data grid.

Here is full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDataGrid from 'react-data-grid';
import { DraggableHeader } from 'react-data-grid-addons';

const { DraggableContainer, DraggableHeaderCell } = DraggableHeader;

const columns = [
  { key: 'id', name: 'ID' },
  { key: 'name', name: 'Name' },
  { key: 'age', name: 'Age' },
];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John', age: 30 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Jane', age: 25 },
  // Add more rows here
];

const MyDataGrid = () => {
  const [gridColumns, setGridColumns] = React.useState(columns);
  const [gridRows, setGridRows] = React.useState(rows);

  const handleColumnReorder = (sourceIdx, targetIdx) => {
    const updatedColumns = [...gridColumns];
    const [columnToReorder] = updatedColumns.splice(sourceIdx, 1);
    updatedColumns.splice(targetIdx, 0, columnToReorder);
    setGridColumns(updatedColumns);
  };

  return (
    <ReactDataGrid
      columns={gridColumns}
      rows={gridRows}
      rowKey="id"
      headerRowHeight={50}
      headerCellRenderer={DraggableHeaderCell}
      draggableHeaderCell={DraggableContainer}
      onHeaderDrop={handleColumnReorder}
    />
  );
};

export default MyDataGrid;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: have you also installed 'react-data-grid-addons'? I also installed that and receive multiple error like this: 'export 'DragItemTypes' (imported as 'DragItemTypes') was not found in 'react-data-grid'.